Unable to find module index.js in Google Cloud VM Docker
I am a facing an error where a docker container is not able to start after deploying to GCP Cloud Compute Engine VM. However, it is able to start normally on my local mac m3 chip machine.
The error pertains to not being able to find module of the index.js.
Node.js v22.3.0

> test-fastify@1.0.0 start
> node build/src/index.js

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1215
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/app/build/src/index.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1212:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1038:27)
    at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:212:19)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:158:5)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:30:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

This is my dockerfile:
FROM node:22

# Create and change to the app directory.
WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

# Install production dependencies.
RUN npm install

# Copy local code to the container image.
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
# Run the web service on container startup.
CMD [ "npm", "run", "build" ]
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]

This is my package.json
{
    "name": "test-fastify",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "tsc -p tsconfig.json",
        "dev": "ts-node-dev --respawn src/index.ts",
        "start": "node build/src/index.js",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "description": "",
    "dependencies": {
        "@fastify/cookie": "^9.3.1",
        "@fastify/cors": "^9.0.1",
        "@fastify/mysql": "^4.3.0",
        "@fastify/session": "^10.9.0",
        "@fastify/type-provider-typebox": "^4.0.0",
        "@sinclair/typebox": "^0.32.30",
        "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
        "fastify": "^4.27.0",
        "firebase": "^10.12.2",
        "firebase-admin": "^12.1.1",
        "kysely": "^0.27.3",
        "mysql2": "^3.9.7",
        "nodemon": "^3.1.0",
        "pino": "^9.1.0",
        "short-uuid": "^5.2.0",
        "uninstall": "^0.0.0",
        "@fastify/swagger": "^8.14.0",
        "@fastify/swagger-ui": "^3.0.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@fastify/autoload": "^5.8.2",
        "@types/node": "^20.12.11",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.11.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.11.0",
        "eslint": "^8.57.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
        "prettier": "^3.2.5",
        "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
        "typescript": "^5.4.5"
    }
}


I have tried to build the image locally as such:
docker build -t gcr.io/some-project-id/fastify-backend-v1 . and tried running it locally but it works. However it failed when it is deployed onto the GCP VM.
tsconfig.json:
{
    "compilerOptions": {    
        /* Language and Environment */
        "target": "es2017" /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */,
        /* Modules */
        "module": "commonjs" /* Specify what module code is generated. */,
        "rootDir": "./" /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */,
        // "moduleResolution": "node10",                     /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */
        "baseUrl": "./" /* Specify the base directory to resolve non-relative module names. */,    
        "outDir": "./build" /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */,        
        "esModuleInterop": true /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */,        
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */,

        /* Type Checking */
        "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,        
        "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
    }
}


Found the solution to be changing the following:
# This runs during container building i.e docker build
RUN npm run build

# This runs when we perform docker start
# Running CMD [NPM, RUN, START] doesnt work
CMD ["node", "build/src/index.js"]

Hence during the building of the container we already compile the code. Perhaps because NPM is not installed (i.e using NVM) during the CMD process, the NPM RUN START command doesn't work
